# CF7 Custom Recipient - Changing the text

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using the CF7 Custom Recipient plugin and i need to change some text on it.

[image]

In that red square i just want to change "CF7 Custom Recipient" to "Enter mail for inquiries" or something like that.

How can i do it?

Comment: To change this, I think you've to change plugin files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this below code into theme's `functions.php` file and check it. see this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/njs8ui)

```
function add_wpcf7_custom_recipient_meta_box_changed() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wpcf7_custom_recipient_meta_box',
        'Enter mail for inquiries', //just here to change text you want
        'show_wpcf7_custom_recipient_meta_box',
        get_post_types(array('public' => true), 'names'),
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_wpcf7_custom_recipient_meta_box_changed' );
```

Comment: @DrawsRenGundam Thank you for this. please click on up arrow for "This answer is useful" so it can help for someone which is finding like this.